# PhpStorm file content not visible after changing to right owner

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I use a program that produces files with **owner root** and **without read access** for other users in a PhpStorm project on Linux. If the file has been accessed by the IDE before (it suffices to have the folder opened in the project menu), even after changing the owner to my user it's still not possible to view the file in PhpStorm.

Is there a solution for this without restarting the IDE?

Steps to reproduce:

```
su;
(umask 007; echo "Hello World!" > test.txt);
exit;
```

Then access the file and execute `sudo chown {current_user}:{current_user} test.txt`. The file content still won't show up in PhpStorm.

Comment: Will `File | Reload All from Disk` show the actual/latest file content?

Comment: @LazyOne
Unfortunately it doesn't.

Comment: Odd... Thanks. My quick search did not return any related tickets. I suggest you contact JetBrains Support directly: it's `Help | Contact Support...` from the IDE menu. There you can privately provide all required files like `idea.log` etc.

Comment: @LazyOne Ok, thanks. Yes, I'll do that, wanted to be sure that I'm not overseeing something.

Comment: Do that. I'd even go and make a ticket right away on [PhpStorm Issue Tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI) (even though it will be moved to the platform-wide IDEA project). It's possible that the ticket already exists and I just have used the wrong keywords etc. If that's the case then the ticket will be marked as a duplicate of exiting one.

Comment: But before that: please double check how it behaves using the latest 2023.1 RC versions (will be released in about 1-1.5 weeks time): https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/nextversion/